# Can I configure TinyMCE to escape (\") double quotes?

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE is escaping quotation marks as named html entities `&quot;` and I need them to be escaped (\"), as this is creating a problem with links in posted content. Is it possible to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to quotes within an HTML attribute its not valid to use `\"` as the escaping mechanism.  You have a few options to be valid.

You can use double quotes for the string delimiter and single quotes within:

```
<option value="'data">value</option>
```

...or vice versa

```
<option value='"data'>value</option>
```

You can use an entity value for the quote in the string:

```
<option value="&quot;data">value</option>
<option value="&#34;data">value</option>
```

But placing `\'` or `\"` within an HTML attribute is not valid HTML.